# How to check BitLocker is supported on the OS via C++?

Tags: compatibility, bitlocker

I would like to get an idea how identify if BitLocker is supported on the OS, may be I need to check some specific registries or settings?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I think I got it.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\BitLocker]
"IsBdeDriverPresent"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. >> 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio‌​n\BitLocker] "IsBdeDriverPresent"=dword:00000001

Comment: This is not correct. My machine has windows 7 Pro, which has no Bitlocker, but this registry IsBdeDriverPresent has value 1

Comment: Win7 Pro still has BitLocker Reader for which it needs the driver, so may be the answer is partially correct. I could not get any closer to the solution.

Comment: Microsoft has published the OS list which supports Bitlocker. Any reason why you did not use that list.